# How to append to json object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

How can I append to a json object.

I define the JSON as follows:

```
$scope.usergroupJson = {'groupId':1,'name':'CEO'}
```

I would like to append `{'groupId':2,'name':'Director'}` to the usergroup. I have tried:

```
$scope.usergroupJson.push({'groupId':2,'name':'Director'});
```

But I get an undefined error. I know this is trivial but any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use like this
    var json = {};
    json["employees"] = [];

```
var usergroupJson = json["employees"];
usergroupJson.push({
    'groupId': 1,
    'name': 'President'
});
usergroupJson.push({
    'groupId': 2,
    'name': 'Vice-President'
});
usergroupJson.push({
    'groupId': 3,
    'name': 'Product Manager'
});
```

Comment: Thanks for putting it all together

Answer (score 4):

you must usergroupJson to be array

`$scope.usergroupJson = [{'groupId':1,'name':'CEO'}]`

Comment: Thanks tried that but it is not what I am after. I would like maintain the JSON format. If I do this I end up getting something in the form of: [0], [1] I would like to get in the form: http://www.w3schools.com/json/

Comment: you getting an array of objects, you cannot have on object with same key's.